# Shortcut keys to move windows between virtual Windows 10 desktops?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-desktop

In Windows 10, are there keyboard shortcut keys to move an application window between virtual Windows desktops?

For example, I remember in Ubuntu, I can press `CTRL+SHIFT+RIGHT` and that will move the active windows to the virtual desktop on the right.

I want to be able move windows between virtual desktops without a mouse or touch screen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The functionality of **moving an existing application to another virtual desktop** exists but isn't mapped to a keyboard shortcut and there seems to be no way, yet, to map it.

That said,

Move to the next Virtual Desktop: `Ctrl + Win + Right Arrow`

Move to the previous Virtual Desktop: `Ctrl + Win + Left Arrow`

Create a new Virtual Desktop (always created to the right of the last desktop): `Ctrl + Win + D`

Show existing Desktops and their overview: `Win + Tab` these are displayed top left

You can then move the desired application between the virtual desktops by dragging it over

[Some general tips to make you more productive](http://www.windowscentral.com/55-shortcuts-and-tips-speed-your-windows-10-experience)

Comment: None of these moved my ACTIVE APPLICATION into the next virtual desktop

Comment: Hmmm, seems like Windows doesn't have that builtin.

Comment: If you change your answer to "This functionality does not exist", then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Win + Tab for the win. No hotkey unfortunately, but before this I had zero ways of moving an application between Desktops. Now at least I have one.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind using AutoHotkey for the purpose, the project [VirtualDesktopAccessor](https://github.com/Ciantic/VirtualDesktopAccessor) comes with an example which does exactly that:

```
hVirtualDesktopAccessor := DllCall("LoadLibrary", Str, "C:\Path\To\VirtualDesktopAccessor.dll", "Ptr")
MoveWindowToDesktopNumberProc := DllCall("GetProcAddress", Ptr, hVirtualDesktopAccessor, AStr, "MoveWindowToDesktopNumber", "Ptr")
GoToDesktopNumberProc := DllCall("GetProcAddress", Ptr, hVirtualDesktopAccessor, AStr, "GoToDesktopNumber", "Ptr")

MoveCurrentWindowToDesktop(number) {
    global MoveWindowToDesktopNumberProc, GoToDesktopNumberProc, activeWindowByDesktop
    WinGet, activeHwnd, ID, A
    DllCall(MoveWindowToDesktopNumberProc, UInt, activeHwnd, UInt, number)
    DllCall(GoToDesktopNumberProc, UInt, number)
}

+#1::MoveCurrentWindowToDesktop(1)
+#2::MoveCurrentWindowToDesktop(2)
+#3::MoveCurrentWindowToDesktop(3)
+#4::MoveCurrentWindowToDesktop(4)
+#5::MoveCurrentWindowToDesktop(5)
```

A collection of nice defaults that makes use of this library is available in https://github.com/yalibian/i3-windows:

> Switch to virtual desktops 1-9 using ⊞-# and backfill # of desktops if needed
>
> Move active windows to virtual desktops 1-9 using ⊞-shift-# and backfill desktops if needed
>
> Close windows with ⊞-shift-q

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be no short cut key but you can google it.
Check to see https://www.howtogeek.com/688224/how-to-move-a-window-to-another-virtual-desktop-on-windows-10/

Here goes descriptions:

1. Open the Task View window (Win + Tab). It will show your all virtual desktops and application windows in thumbnail icons.
2. In Task View, Find your application thumbnail then right click on the thumbnail and select 'Move to'.
3. Select the destination desktop.

That's all folks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread has been dead a while now, but thought I'd mention that Michael Zomparelli has created an app called zVirtualDesktop that has a ton of functionality including the feature of a hotkey to move windows between virtual desktops. It has a free ten day trial but then is paid unfortunately. You can find the app here: https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

[image: Here's an example of this in the app.]